# CUDA missing libGL.so libGLU.so and libX11.so

Tags: opengl, cuda, linux-mint

This is the standard problem that people have been running across, but I can't get it to work.  I'm on Linux Mint 17.3 and did the install via repo.  When I try to compile the 5_Simulations directory (really, fluidsGL), I get the following errors:

```
>>> WARNING - libGL.so not found, refer to CUDA Getting Started Guide for how to find and install them. <<<
>>> WARNING - libGLU.so not found, refer to CUDA Getting Started Guide for how to find and install them. <<<
>>> WARNING - libX11.so not found, refer to CUDA Getting Started Guide for how to find and install them. <<<
```

However, these do exist on the system, for example:

```
[name@host: fluidsGL]$ locate libGL.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2.0
/usr/lib/nvidia-352/libGL.so
/usr/lib/nvidia-352/libGL.so.1
/usr/lib/nvidia-352/libGL.so.352.68
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2.0
/usr/lib32/nvidia-352/libGL.so
/usr/lib32/nvidia-352/libGL.so.1
/usr/lib32/nvidia-352/libGL.so.352.6
```

Even symlinking to /usr/lib/libGL.so with the nvidia-352 version doesn't work.  Has anybody had this particular issue?  I'm trying not to screw up the computer, as I've had issues with drivers suddenly not working when I start messing with this kind of stuff.

Comment: FYI Linux Mint is not an [officially supported distro for CUDA](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#system-requirements).  After you've made that symlink, try `GLPATH=/usr/lib make` instead of the `make` you were issuing to build the sample(s).

Comment: The GLPATH worked perfectly!  Thank you!

Comment: @NuclearAlchemist: if that was the solution to your problem, could you add it in a short answer. You will later be able to accept your own answer, which marks the question as solved and gets it off the unanswered question list.

Comment: @talonmies Just did so, I didn't get a chance to do it the other day.  Brain fart.

Comment: Thanks for doing that.

Comment: confirming that GLPATH=/usr/lib make works for debian 8 (also an unsupported os)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Linux Mint is not an [officially supported distro for CUDA](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#system-requirements).  So it's possible that the CUDA install method (the driver install portion, in this case) you are using is placing the necessary GL libraries in a place that the makefile is not equipped to find.

If you study the `findgllib.mk` makefile "helper" file in the build directory, I suspect a debian based distribution would follow the `UBUNTU` path in that `.mk` file.  For the non-ppc and non-arm branches, you will find definitions like this:

```
ifeq ("$(UBUNTU)","0")
  ifeq ...
  ...
  else
    GLPATH    ?= /usr/lib/$(UBUNTU_PKG_NAME)
    GLLINK    ?= -L/usr/lib/$(UBUNTU_PKG_NAME)
    DFLT_PATH ?= /usr/lib
```

Given that:

1. You have stated that the GL libraries seemed to be installed.
2. You've symlinked those libraries into the /usr/lib directory
3. The GLPATH definition in the `.mk` file is a "non-override" definition (i.e. `?=`)

we can "override" or replace the GLPATH definition concocted by the makefile with the "known good" one of `/usr/lib` with:

```
GLPATH=/usr/lib
```

prepended to your `make` command.

Answer (score 0):

the same problem occurs to me and i tried all including driver installtion but when i watched the makefile(.mk) there is graphic driver version specified and it checks for OS distribution name like(Ubuntu, fedora etc) while i was using Zorin so it wasn't able to find path assigned to variables. so after miner changes it runs successfully. i hope it help.

The changes were:

// whatever version u have

```
UBUNTU_PKG_NAME = "nvidia-375"
```

// add name of distro in this list

```
 ifeq (,$(filter $(DISTRO),ubuntu zorin fedora red rhel centos suse))
   DISTRO = 
 endif
```

// add this line for specific distro

```
ZORIN = $(shell echo $(DISTRO) | grep -i zorin      >/dev/null 2>&1; echo $$?)
```

//copy and paste same code which has for ubuntu in file for your specified distro if required

```
ifeq ("$(ZORIN)","0")
  ifeq ($(HOST_ARCH)-$(TARGET_ARCH),x86_64-armv7l)
    GLPATH := /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib
    GLLINK := -L/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib
    ifneq ($(TARGET_FS),) 
      GLPATH += $(TARGET_FS)/usr/lib/$(UBUNTU_PKG_NAME)
      GLPATH += $(TARGET_FS)/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
      GLLINK += -L$(TARGET_FS)/usr/lib/$(UBUNTU_PKG_NAME)
      GLLINK += -L$(TARGET_FS)/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
    endif 
  else ifeq ($(HOST_ARCH)-$(TARGET_ARCH),x86_64-ppc64le)
    GLPATH := /usr/powerpc64le-linux-gnu/lib
    GLLINK := -L/usr/powerpc64le-linux-gnu/lib
  else
    GLPATH    ?= /usr/lib/$(UBUNTU_PKG_NAME)
    GLLINK    ?= -L/usr/lib/$(UBUNTU_PKG_NAME)
    DFLT_PATH ?= /usr/lib
  endif
endif
```

Answer (score 0):

For plain Debian you might want to use the following:

```
…
SUSE   = $(shell echo $(DISTRO) | grep -i 'suse\|sles' >/dev/null 2>&1; echo $$?)
DEBIAN = $(shell echo $(DISTRO) | grep -i debian       >/dev/null 2>&1; echo $$?)

ifeq ("$(UBUNTU)","0")
…
```

```
…
ifeq ("$(CENTOS)","0")
  GLPATH    ?= /usr/lib64/nvidia
  GLLINK    ?= -L/usr/lib64/nvidia
  DFLT_PATH ?= /usr/lib64
endif
ifeq ("$(DEBIAN)","0")
  GLPATH    ?= /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
  GLLINK    ?= -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
  DFLT_PATH ?= /usr/lib64
endif

# find libGL, libGLU 
…
```

in your `cuda-samples/common/findgllib.mk`, then enter `cuda-samples` and execute `for f in $(find ?_* -name findgllib.mk); do cp -bv common/findgllib.mk $f; done` to use that file for every GL sample